# Keep default beamer bibliography but change citation style

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

I would like to change the citation style to (author, year) while keeping the default bibliography style in beamer.

All solutions I found include using natbib, which works well but changes the appearance of the bibliography.

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```